# TensorFlow: "Attempting to use uninitialized value" in variable initialization

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, tensorflow

I am trying to implement multivariate linear regression in Python using TensorFlow, but have run into some logical and implementation issues. My code throws the following error:

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
Caused by op u'Variable/read'
```

Ideally the `weights` output should be `[2, 3]`

```
def hypothesis_function(input_2d_matrix_trainingexamples,
                        output_matrix_of_trainingexamples,
                        initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function,
                        learning_rate, num_steps):
    # calculate num attributes and num examples
    number_of_attributes = len(input_2d_matrix_trainingexamples[0])
    number_of_trainingexamples = len(input_2d_matrix_trainingexamples)

    #Graph inputs
    x = []
    for i in range(0, number_of_attributes, 1):
        x.append(tf.placeholder("float"))
    y_input = tf.placeholder("float")

    # Create Model and Set Model weights
    parameters = []
    for i in range(0, number_of_attributes, 1):
        parameters.append(
            tf.Variable(initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function[i]))

    #Contruct linear model
    y = tf.Variable(parameters[0], "float")
    for i in range(1, number_of_attributes, 1):
        y = tf.add(y, tf.multiply(x[i], parameters[i]))

    # Minimize the mean squared errors
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_input))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    #Initialize the variables
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    # launch the graph
    session = tf.Session()
    session.run(init)
    for step in range(1, num_steps + 1, 1):
        for i in range(0, number_of_trainingexamples, 1):
            feed = {}
            for j in range(0, number_of_attributes, 1):
                array = [input_2d_matrix_trainingexamples[i][j]]
                feed[j] = array
            array1 = [output_matrix_of_trainingexamples[i]]
            feed[number_of_attributes] = array1
            session.run(train, feed_dict=feed)

    for i in range(0, number_of_attributes - 1, 1):
        print (session.run(parameters[i]))

array = [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, 2.0, 3.0], [0.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
hypothesis_function(array, [8.0, 13.0, 23.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 0.01, 200)
```

Comment: What line do you get the exception on?

Comment: @Daniel Slater at line :- parameters.append(tf.Variable(initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function[i]))

Comment: OK, is initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function an array of tf.variable? If so that is your problem.

Comment: Yes at very last line it is [1.0,1.0,1.0] What should be then ?

Comment: Can you include the code to generate the initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function in your sample? (Also to make it smaller removing everything after the line with the exception)

Comment: At very end of code snippet there is code to initialize initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function

Comment: If the issue is on gcloud - check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384189/4137497

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from the code example, but if the list `initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function` is a list of `tf.Variable` objects, then the line `session.run(init)` will fail because TensorFlow isn't (yet) smart enough to figure out the dependencies in variable initialization. To work around this, you should change the loop that creates `parameters` to use [`initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function[i].initialized_value()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.initialized_value), which adds the necessary dependency:

```
parameters = []
for i in range(0, number_of_attributes, 1):
    parameters.append(tf.Variable(
        initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function[i].initialized_value()))
```

Comment: That worked but now it gives error :- TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a int into a Tensor. at line session.run(train, feed_dict=feed)

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong: the keys of the `feed` dictionary must be `Tensor` objects (typically `tf.placeholder()` tensors) and not `int` values. You probably want to replace `feed[j] = array` with `feed[x[j]] = array`.

Comment: Running the `train` op (returned by `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer().minimize(loss)`) while feeding in different training examples seems like a good start. If you have more specific questions, feel free to ask another question!

Comment: although now my code runs correct , it gives same value of parameters as initial value with  which i initialize

Comment: This can happen if your parameters are stuck in a local minimum. A common error is to initialize all of your weights to zero - instead you should initialize them randomly (using e.g. `tf.truncated_normal()`).

Comment: Shouldn't be that `parameters.append(tf.Variable(initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function[i]).initialized_value())` as `initial_parameters_of_hypothesis_function` is a list in OP. Also the https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.initialized_value refers to an older version of the API - what would be the right way to this now ?

Answer (score 71):

Run this:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

Or (depending on the version of TF that you have):

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

Comment: Excusde me `initialize_all_variables` is deprecated - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables

Comment: hmm, why is this not the top answer?

Comment: @Zuoanqh  exactly! even I have the same question

Answer (score 5):

There is another the error happening which related to the order when calling initializing global variables. I've had the sample of code has similar error **FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value W**

```
def linear(X, n_input, n_output, activation = None):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_output], stddev=0.1), name='W')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32, shape=[n_output]), name='b')
    if activation != None:
        h = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W),b), name='h')
    else:
        h = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W),b, name='h')
    return h

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.get_default_graph()
print([op.name for op in g.get_operations()])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # RUN INIT
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # But W hasn't in the graph yet so not know to initialize 
    # EVAL then error
    print(linear(np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0]]).astype(np.float32), 3, 3).eval())
```

You should change to following

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.get_default_graph()
print([op.name for op in g.get_operations()])
with tf.Session() as 
    # NOT RUNNING BUT ASSIGN
    l = linear(np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0]]).astype(np.float32), 3, 3)
    # RUN INIT
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print([op.name for op in g.get_operations()])
    # ONLY EVAL AFTER INIT
    print(l.eval(session=sess))
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally there are two ways of initializing variables, 1) using the `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` as the previous answers noted; 2) the load the graph from checkpoint.

You can do like this:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=3)
try:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.model_dir))
    # start from the latest checkpoint, the sess will be initialized 
    # by the variables in the latest checkpoint
except ValueError:
    # train from scratch
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
```

And the third method is to use the [tf.train.Supervisor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor). The session will be

> Create a session on 'master', recovering or initializing the model as needed, or wait for a session to be ready.

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor([parameters])
sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session()
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to give my resolution, it work when i replace the line `[session = tf.Session()]` with `[sess = tf.InteractiveSession()]`. Hope this will be useful to others.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed helpful for me while running on Jupyter Notebook. Can explain why does it work though?

Comment: @shubhamsingh Interactive Session is used for the entire instance of the notebook. So your session is always on. However, if we use tensorflow.Session() it is only for a specific region. For instance we use ``with`` keyword
like (`with tf.Session as sess:`)

Answer (score 3):

run both:

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())