# Tensorflow optimizer variable initialization mystery and SIGKILL strike out of nowhere

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, initialization, out-of-memory

I am trying to build my own tensorflow optimizer making a subclass of the Optimizer class. But I am running into problems when trying to use it.

If I try to use it normally, it tells me that one of the variables of my model (not an optimizer variable) is not initialized but this problem doesn't occur if I use another optimizer so obviously I am initializing that variable properly and the problem lies with my optimizer. And very very strangely, it fails at the line

```
tfsession.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

to which I get the error:

> 2017-03-28 21:21:29,422 FailedPreconditionError
>
> 2017-03-28 21:21:29,423 :
>
> 2017-03-28 21:21:29,423 Attempting to use uninitialized value decoder/dec_5/fc/W
>        [[Node: decoder/dec_5/fc/W/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@decoder/dec_5/fc/W"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

So it is attempting to use a variable during the initializing variables ... how is that possible?!

So anyway, if I try to solve the problem by first making sure all the variables of the model and then initializing the rest of the variables I get something even weirder: a terminate signal strikes down unexpectidely from the heavens!!

Concretely I split up the initialization as:

```
    tfsession.run(tf.variables_initializer([gs]))
    logger.info("POINT 1")
    tfsession.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.trainable_variables()))
    logger.info("POINT 2")
    tfsession.run(tf.variables_initializer([v for v in tf.global_variables() if v not in tf.trainable_variables()+[gs]]))
    logger.info("POINT 3")
```

(`gs` is the global step of the optimizer, and for some reason apparently in some optimizers must be initialized before the other variables)

An this gives me the following when I run it:

> 2017-03-28 21:42:52,799 Initializing variables
>
> 2017-03-28 21:42:58,345 POINT 1
>
> 2017-03-28 21:42:58,840 POINT 2
>
> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

I get a SIGKILL that comes out of nowhere!?! What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

So thanks to this answer from @mrry : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016117/3990607
I was able to figure out that when I initialize variables in my optimizer which are dependent on trainable variables `v` then I should use `v.initialized_value()` and not `v`.

Here is how my variables are created in my optimizer:

```
def _create_slots(self, var_list):
    if (self._Rt is None or
                self._Rt.graph is not var_list[0].graph):
        with ops.colocate_with(var_list[0]):
            self._Rt = linalg_ops.eye(self.y_dim, dtype=np.float32,
                                   name="R") / self._lr


    for v in var_list:
        self._get_or_make_slot(v, linalg_ops.eye(gen_array_ops.size(v.initialized_value()),
                                              dtype=v.dtype.base_dtype) * self.Q, "Q", self._name)
        self._get_or_make_slot(v, linalg_ops.eye(gen_array_ops.size(v.initialized_value()),
                                              dtype=v.dtype.base_dtype) * self.P0, "P", self._name)
```

I think this solved some of the problem, because now when I initialize the variables using

```
tfsession.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

I pass directly to the `SIGKILL` error mentioned previously.

**Update 2:**

It seems to be some sort of memory issue. When I look at what happens in /var/log/system.log while it dies, I see:

> kernel[0]: low swap: killing pid 68269 (python3.5)
>
> kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 18384 [com.apple.audio.]
>
> com.apple.CDScheduler[265]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0 
>   com.apple.CDScheduler[44]: Thermal pressure state: 1 Memory pressure state: 0 com.apple.CDScheduler[265]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure state: 0 
>   com.apple.CDScheduler[44]: Thermal pressure state: 0 Memory pressure
>   state: 0